# Raspberry Pi 3 with CentOS no SSH without a keyboard

Tags: pi-3, boot, keyboard

I installed CentOS 7.4 (1708) Minimal on a fresh Raspberry Pi 3 without issues. But I am struggeling with SSH connections, although each time the network is reachable from the Raspberry:

- If a keyboard or a keyboard USB dongle is attached to the Raspberry at boot time SSH works perfectly fine
- If the keyboard dongle is never attached, no SSH connection can be established with a `Network error: Connection timed out`
- If the keyboard dongle is attached after booting, the keyboard works, but the Raspberry can still not be connected to via SSH

I had a similar problem with a x86_64 server and could solve it allowing the BIOS to boot without a keyboard. But here the Raspberry boots correctly, but still does not allow any SHH connections.

Any suggestions what  I could do?

Comment: How do you connect to the network? Through ethernet interface or through wifi? I ask because ethernet interface is an (internal) usb device.

Comment: Ahh we're getting closer! I try to connect through ethernet. When the Raspberry boots and is not reachable, it helps to reconnect the ethernet cable. Then it works without problems with or without keyboard and monitor. Any suggestions where that comes from?

Comment: No, not really. I'm also fighting with this odd [ethernet interface interrupts connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79359/79866).

Comment: Is CentOS 7.4 (1708) Minimal using `systemd`?

Comment: Yes it does indeed! I used your test to track the pings, but as soon as I can create a connection mine are 100% stable.

Comment: Thanks for the test. I will look now at `systemd`.